# SSRS multiple line detail section different column width

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with many columns that needs to span multiple lines on the detail section to all appear on pdf report in landscape view.

Is there a way to adjust the column widths of each of the lines independently of one another?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to post a screen shot of what you expect it to look like but if I understood, you can add a rectangle inside a single cell on the details rowgroup and then just add textboxes as you like. It's a bit manual but should work

Comment: I ended up merging cells as needed to account for the columns that are no longer. Thanks